# javascript, jquery will not show images at 15" screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

At a website I am displaying images in 5x 5 grid, using . On the last picture, custom parts, I wish to display a rotating images. This panelGallery js script works fine on all screen sizes apart from 15"  screen, when testing, where the whole of the 15" screen is gets occupied by magnified version of the small rotating images, covering all the images behind.
Any help to solve this pestering problem would be much welcome.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"     
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.panelgallery-1_1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('#container').panelGallery();
});
</script>
<script>
if( self == top ) {
    document.documentElement.style.display = 'block' ; 
 } else {
    top.location = self.location ; 
 }
 </script>


</head>


<div  class="PZ3zoom PZ3-r Bdr Cap Lnk" style="width:130px; height:104px;"><a href="http://www.hpcgears.com/n/products/16.custom_products/custom_parts.php" onclick="return true">

        <div id="container">

            <img alt="" src="1.images/images_special/plastic1.jpg" name="tb" width="130" height="104"/>

            <img alt="" src="1.images/images_special/gear.jpg" name="tb" width="130" height="104"/>
            <img alt="" src="1.images/images_special/gear2.jpg" name="tb" width="130" height="104"/>
            <img alt="" src="1.images/images_special/custom1.gif" name="tb" width="130" height="104" />
            <img alt="" src="1.images/images_special/double_gears.jpg" name="tb" width="130" height="104"/>
            <img alt="" src="1.images/images_special/gearbox.jpg" name="tb" width="130" height="104"/>
            <img alt="" src="1.images/images_special/gearbox3.jpg" name="tb" width="130" height="104"/>
            <img alt="" src="1.images/images_special/custom2.gif" name="tb" width="130" height="104" />
            <img alt="" src="1.images/images_special/gearbox2.jpg" name="tb" width="130" height="104"/>
            <img alt="" src="1.images/images_special/gear3.jpg" name="tb" width="130" height="104"/></div>
<span class="PZ3inr"> <em><span style="color:#ccf; background:inherit;">Custom parts</span></em></span></span></a>
```

Custom Parts

Comment: Is the 15" screen using a different browser or resolution? What happens when you resize your browser window in a larger screen?

Comment: The page works fine in  all browsers windows,Mac etc its just the screen size that causes problem in 15" windows 8 only. Resizing the screen on 15" doesn't change anything.

Comment: What browser are you using for the 15" screen? IE 11?

Since you seem to be measuring everything in pixels, you biggest culprits are going to be resolution and browser vendor. You may also check to see what mode it's being rendered in with IE. You may check out another PC running the same version of IE.

Another guess is that when you say 15" screen, you're talking about a tablet or laptop. Make sure that you don't have a setting set to enhance the display of the webpage. Also try running it with a different browser on the 15" screen.

Comment: The 15" is the physical monitor size on a desktop PC running windows 8. I have tried on two different 15" monitors both running windows 8 and the same thing happens there. On Mac and PC over 15" physical screen everything is just fine.

Comment: It's likely the browser, not the monitor. You have to code to the browser's quirks.

Comment: latest: just tried it on the other 15" monitor and on this one, it displays the rotating images, which is 130x104px, on top left hand corner of the screen. It does what it should do, but not in its allocated <div> place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A live example would help provide a better example.
however, here's my fix - not knowing all the moving parts(css, the js library you are using, etc..). So I suggest making a CSS class and creating a fixed max width to prevent it from displaying huge at 15 inches wide.

Try a media over-ride on the container

```
<div class="container">...</div>
```

a CSS solution

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1800px)  {
    .container { width:1800; }  
}
```

or you just just set a max-width on that div

```
.container { max-width:1800px; }
```

Now instead of 1800px use whatever screen width the images displayed correctly at.

Comment: Tried that. No difference.

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that if I keep the cursor on the problem <div> that rotates images, it all works fine. As soon as I move the cursor away from the image/<div>, thats when it starts behaving badly.Thought that might help